# Upgrading CakePHP web site to PHP 7

Tags: php, cakephp, basic-authentication

I've taken over a website written for PHP 5.4 and Cake2.x.  I upgraded PHP to 7.2 and Cake to 2.10.  Now no one can log in.  I started debugging but I feel like I'm going down a rabbit-hole.  In `FormAuthenticate::authenticate(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response)` is the statement `$fields = $this->settings['fields'];` after which I added `$ex = fopen('php://stderr', 'a'); 
 fputs($ex, "fields=" . json_encode($fields) . "\n");` which output

```
fields={"username":"username","password":"password"}
```

rather than the actual username and password which I'd typed on the web page.  I tried re-assigning `fields` with the actual username and password but the function calls method `_checkFields` which calls `$request->data` which returns an empty string.

Obviously I am taking the wrong approach here.  I've done something wrong in the upgrade, or omitted to do something;  something beyond just changing `composer.json` and running `composer update`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The `fields` option doesn't hold any user data, it's a map that defines the names of the fields in the form data and in the database, see **https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers**. So if your form and database fields are named `username` and `password`, then leave the option alone and let it use the defaults.

Comment: If `$request->data` is empty (I assume it's not actually a string, as that would yield an error when it's being accessed as an array - make sure that debug mode and error reporting are enabled), then there's your problem, but that could be caused by so many things (redirects, data not being sent, it's being overwritten/removed, etc...), it's almost impossible for anyone here to tell, you'll have to do some more debugging to figure where the data is being lost.

Comment: Cake 2 uses mcrypt that is not supported by default in php 7.2, https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html, either use php 7.1 or install mcryt

Comment: I really can't believe I'm having to do this low-level debugging on what is a fairly mature package.  Anyway, I debugged.  mcrypt is already installed, so it's not that, but thanks for the suggestion, Nathaniel.  `$request->data()` calls `CakeRequest::data()` which returns (via the final statement) `Hash::get($this->data, $name)`.  *That* ends up returning `$default`, which is `null`.  So presumably it's expected that `$data` has a key `User` but it doesn't.  So I suppose I have to work out how `$request->data` does _not_ contain key `User`.

Comment: I just deleted Vendor/ (yes, it is Vendor/ in this application for some reason) and composer installed afresh.  Now, in Hash::get, `$data={"user":null}` and `$path='User.email'` followed by `$data={"user":null}` and `$path='User.password'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem by downgrading CakePHP to version 2.9.9.